# Add weather/images to GMap given the bounding coordinates.

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have images of weather and other images that I would like to add to the GMap. I also have the bounding coordinates of these images(all 4 corners lat/lng). Now I just need to overlay these images to the map and bound them inside the coordinates. I have looked at the Demo.Clouds testing file for GMap and messed with it but I have no idea how I can integrate these bounding coordinates. Let me know if there is confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The approach would be to create custom markers (as seen [in the sources](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/Markers/GMarkerGoogle.cs)) adding your weather icons and place them at the midpoints of your bounding boxes (simple average calculation of the coordinates).

Do you also need to highlight the areas? Then you could add polygons [`GMapPolygon`](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapPolygon.cs).